# Smoothly resizing a component over a transparent container in swing

Tags: java, swing, resize, awt, alpha-transparency

I have made a transparent container(JWindow) which contains a resizable rectangle(JLabel having 10px thick border). Similar to http://www.screenleap.com/.

I made the JWindow transparent using AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(JWindow, false).

The problem is, while resizing the rectangle, if mouse goes outside the rectangle bounds, it stops resizing. Its because the parent JWindow is transparent and it does not listen to mouse events over the transparent part.

How to resize the rectangle smoothly in this situation? So that the mouse does not go out of the rectangle bounds while resizing.

Thanx

Comment: for better help sooner edit your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and Java version and Native OS